# Xubuntu 14.04, Power Manager, Screensaver

Tags: power-management, lock-screen, screensaver

When my computer is inactive, I keep getting a black screen and the screen goes into locked mode asking for a password, even though in Power Manager I have "Never" set for actions and monitor and Extended "Lock Screen" is unchecked. I don't see a screensaver, but perhaps that is the issue?

Is anyone else experiencing this?
Is this a bug?
Is there a temporary workaround?

I did not see this issue in 12.xx, 13.xx.

Comment: I may have fixed this. Light Locker Settings. Set everything to Off and Never. Will post again if still having issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think for me, clicking All Settings (quad square in lower right of launcher pull-down menu), launching Light Locker Settings, and switching Enable Light Locker to OFF